# Catching ball - finding the maximum number of caught balls

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

I'm attempting to solve the following problem:

> Balls are falling from the sky. We know at which location (on a
>   straight line) will each ball drop, and we know the time (in seconds)
>   at which will the ball reach the ground. We are trying to catch them
>   into a ball net, which we can move left or right, but each movement
>   costs 1 second. The initial position of a ballnet is always on the left (position 0). We are allowed to > drop (not catch) $k$ number of balls.
>
> What is the highest score we can achieve?

My first attempt at solving this was a greedy algorithm:

```
if the |next ball position - current position of the ball net| > (time of the next ball - current time) 
     then attempts++
     if attempts>$k$
           print game over
else
     current ball net position = next ball position
     current time = time of the next ball
     score++
```

however my algorithm doesn't take into consideration that sometimes it's better to sacrifice some number of balls in order to reach a higher score in the long run. This needs an approach via dynamic programming, I think.

Is this problem a known one so I can find some help? Could you help me with this problem? I can solve this in a greedy way, however I am failing to do it dynamically.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a competition or homework problem. Could you provide a link to the competition, so we know it's no longer active? Thanks.

Comment: @j_random_hacker it's not a competition, it's a problem from my advanced algorithms class.

Comment: OK, hint: See if you can compute the largest number of balls that you can catch *given that you are at position $i$ a few milliseconds before time $t$*.

Comment: Try dynamic progtramming.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info